# Recieving 303 Error Code in external script Moodle

Tags: php, apache, error-handling, moodle, http-status-code-303

I have written an external script to update user data in moodle. I included moodle/onfig.php file in the external script. When I access the external script I receive 303 error and redirected to dashboard page, I cannot share the code.

```
<?php
  require_once('../config.php');
  if (!empty($CFG->forcelogin) or !isloggedin()) {
     echo "<a href='$CFG->wwwroot/login/' target='_blank'>you are not logged in.</a><br/>";
     exit();
  }
?>
```

when I comment the `require_once('../config.php');` the script is working fine. But I need the config file to update users data.

Comment: Why are you using `or` instead of `||`?

Comment: my bad it should be `||` but I have commented out the if block and leaving `require_once('../config.php');` the page is still returning 303 , as soon as I comment `require_once('../config.php');` error disappears and I can also access the page.

Comment: HTTP 303 is NOT a error, but a redirect...

Comment: but I want to understand the page is being redirected

Comment: For waht purpose you are using the following line  
`if (!empty($CFG->forcelogin) or !isloggedin()) {` is it just for checking the user is signed in?

Comment: to force login user through moodle